# How can I get an Enum from an object values in Java?

Tags: java

I want to create an Enum of all StandardCharsets elements ("UTF_8", "UTF_16LE", "UTF_16BE", "UTF_16", "US_ASCII" and "ISO_8859_1").

Is it possible?

This is what I have inside enum file but it gives me syntax error:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public enum CharsetEnum {
    
    StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1,  // Syntax error on token ".", ( expected
    StandardCharsets.US_ASCII,
    StandardCharsets.UTF_16,
    StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE,
    StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE,
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    
    private String label;
    
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    private CharsetEnum(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't create an enum of another type.  You could have an enum that has a field of another type.

Comment: What is this going to give you above `StandardCharsets` itself though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, it can be like this:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public enum CharsetEnum {

    ISO_8859_1(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
    US_ASCII(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII),
    UTF_16(StandardCharsets.UTF_16),
    UTF_16BE(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE),
    UTF_16LE(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE),
    UTF_8(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);


    private final Charset label;

    public Charset getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    CharsetEnum(Charset label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```